# Is there any good reference on the Bayesian view that can be helpful for reading papers on the number theory using heuristic arguments?

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, algebraic-number-theory, bayesian-probability, heuristics

Nowadays there are many papers on the number theory using heuristics.

I have read some of them.
But I have no clear understanding of the Bayesian Probability(subjective probability).

The concept of using probabilistic method for a deterministic object is not clear at least to me.

Is there any good exposition on the Bayesian Probability especially for number theorists?

Thank you.

Comment: Possibly relevant paper https://arxiv.org/abs/1707.08747 .

Comment: Surjective or subjective?

Comment: @SylvainJULIEN  I meant subjective, I've edited it. thank you.

Comment: By the way, it would be interesting to establish some kind of "extremal probability entropy principle", which would allow to determine which probability distribution is best suited to apprehend a deterministic mathematical phenomenon heuristically.

Comment: @SylvainJULIEN I agree with that. And I hope those discussions could become easily accessible to number theorists. Is the 'extremal probability entropy principle' a well established concept? If so can you suggest a good reference please?

Comment: I don't know actually. I was just trying to draw a parallel with both the maximum entropy principle and the extremal action principle in physics (I studied physics). A fun fact is that these two principles can be expressed as $\delta S=0$ with of course different meanings for the symbol $S$! But the Shannon entropy of a probability distribution is well defined, so you should be able to find relevant references about it.